# How can I change ubuntu 16.04 LTS wallpaper to a custom image?

Tags: 16.04

I know that there are some options for wallpapers on Ubuntu, but how to pick up a custom image and set as wallpaper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just Rightclick on any image and "Set as wallpaper"

[image]